# Python Pandas SUMPRODUCT and L Matrix caluclation

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy-einsum

i have to columns in a pandas dataframe format and want the output in the C  D column as below

```
 A   B   C             D
 1   2   1*2           1*2
 3   4   (1+3)*4       (1*2)+(3*4)
 5   6   (1+3+5)*6     (1*2)+(3*4)+(5*6)
 7   8   (1+3+5+7)*8   (1*2)+(3*4)+(5*6)+(7*8)
 9   10  ....          .....
```

Here i am trying to code excel formula in a python way ,Can someone throw code for this

```
a) python code for top to bottom calculation
Excel Formulas for the final outcome:
C1=IFERROR($B2*SUM(A2:$A$2)-SUMPRODUCT($B2:B$2,$A2:A$2),0)
C2=IFERROR($B3*SUM(A$2:$A3)-SUMPRODUCT($B$2:B3,$A$2:A3),0)
.....
....
C14=IFERROR($B14*SUM(A$2:$A14)-SUMPRODUCT($B$2:B14,$A$2:A14),0)

b) python code for bottom to top calculation from bottom
e1==IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT($B2:B$14,$C2:C$14)-$B2*SUM($C2:C$14),0)
E2=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT($B3:B$14,$C3:C$14)-$B3*SUM($C3:C$14),0)
e4=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT($B4:B$14,$C4:C$14)-$B4*SUM($C4:C$14),0)
.....
.....
.....
e14=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT($B14:B$14,$C14:C$14)-$B14*SUM($C14:C$14),0)
```

Comment: Why do you use `IFERROR(..)` here?

Comment: Hi Willem the IFERROR is used to result the zero value if the outcome is negative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) with multiple by [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mul.html):

```
df['C'] = df['A'].cumsum().mul(df['B'])
df['D'] = df[['A', 'B']].prod(1).cumsum()
```

Or:

```
df = df.assign(C=df['A'].cumsum().mul(df['B']),
               D=df['A'].mul(df['B']).cumsum())

print (df)
   A   B    C    D
0  1   2    2    2
1  3   4   16   14
2  5   6   54   44
3  7   8  128  100
4  9  10  250  190
```

EDIT:

For reverse values is simpliest use `iloc[::-1]`:

```
df = df.assign(C=df['A'].iloc[::-1].cumsum().mul(df['B']),
               D=df[['A', 'B']].iloc[::-1].prod(1).cumsum())

print (df)
   A   B    C    D
0  1   2   50  190
1  3   4   96  188
2  5   6  126  176
3  7   8  128  146
4  9  10   90   90
```

EDIT1:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,3,5,7,9], 'B':[2,4,6,8,10]})
df['C']=df['A'].iloc[::-1].cumsum().mul(df['B'])
df['D']=df[['A', 'B']].iloc[::-1].prod(1).cumsum()

print (df)
   A   B    C    D
0  1   2   50  190
1  3   4   96  188
2  5   6  126  176
3  7   8  128  146
4  9  10   90   90

#create index by column A
x = df.set_index('A')
print (x)
    B    C    D
A              
1   2   50  190
3   4   96  188
5   6  126  176
7   8  128  146
9  10   90   90

#get index of minimal value by D column
print (x['D'].idxmin())
9
```

Comment: thanks for your update this will surely work for the query a)  that is calculating from top to bottom ,to use this same approach to calculate the data from bottom to up what should be done ?   i mean b) python code for bottom to top calculation from bottom of the above question start the calculation from cell 14 and store and then cell14 and cell13 store and cell14,cell13 and cell12 etc . basically the same calculation in reverse order.

Comment: it works ,plain example code you have given works ,somehow i could not use the .assign function given by you. i have another query in the same suppose in the D column need to check what is the minimum value and its lookup of A then assign this to variable how to do this ?  example Min of D is 90 so it is A value is 9 assign this 9 to a variable .

Comment: No problem, assign is not necessary, only use first solurion. For lookup the nest is use `df = df.set_index('D')` and then `x = df.loc[90, 'A']` it assign value 9 to variable x.

Comment: Jezreal this does error in result AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'min'  basically i used    new_table is nothing but pandas dataframe array                                                                                           new_table = new_table.set_index('D')
x = new_table.loc[['D'].min(axis=1),[ 'A']]  it throws the error , basically i want to logically check what is the minimum value of D column and lookup A column to its equivalent value and put it in x variable ;any other method ?

Comment: Glad can help you!